Find unknown primes from two RSA modulus
Suppose that $$, $$, and $$ are $512$-bit primes and for some integer $ < 10^5$, $ + $ is also prime. We know the moduli $_1 =  × $ and $_2 = ( + ) × $. Can we recover the primes $p$, $$, and $$ from this information?

@kelalaka Just $n_1$ and $n_2$ are known to us.

Could you provide us with the origin of this question?

The specific case $a=2$ was considered here.

This can be solved by carrying out exhaustive search on $a$ (the search space is only around $2^{15}$ after all) and applying the bivariate Coppersmith theorem for each candidate value of $a$. As a reminder, the theorem says the following:

Let $P(x,y)$ be an irreducible polynomial in two variables over $\mathbb{Z}$, of maximum degree $\delta$ in each variable independently, and $X,Y\leq 1$ be some bounds on the desired solutions $x_0, y_0$. Define $\tilde{P}(x,y) = P(xX,yY)$ and let $W$ be the supremum of the absolute values of the coefficients of $\tilde{P}$. Under the condition that $XY \leq W^{2/(3\delta)}$, one can find all integer pairs $(x_0,y_0)$ with
$P(x_0,y_0) = 0$, $|x0| \leq X$ and $|y_0| \leq Y$ in time polynomial in $\log W$ and $2^\delta$.

In the case of this question, I take $P(x,y) = axy - N_2 x + N_1 y$, which is a polynomial of degree $\delta=1$ independently in $x$ and $y$. I claim that $(x_0,y_0)=(q,r)$ is a small solution. Indeed, $P(x_0,y_0) = aqr - N_2 q + N_1 r = aqr - (p+a)qr + pqr = 0$. Moreover, if I set $X=Y=2^{512}$, $W=\max(aXY, N_2 X, N_1 Y)\approx 2^{1536}$, and therefore the condition $XY\leq W^{2/3}$ is satisfied, so Coppersmith gives an efficient algorithm to find $q,r$, which obviously solves the problem.
Where does the question come from, by the way? I haven't seen it addressed directly in a cursory literature review, so if it is related to some sort of realistic scenario (some kind of fault attack?), it might be interesting to write up.

If someone uses a sieve to pre-select the prime factors of a batch of RSA-moduli, (s)he could get the idea to pick more than one prime from the sieve.
